Styling Dash Datatable Column Header text or Sortable Icon
I want to add a margin between the sort icon and the column header text. I have tried adding margin to the header styling and this does not give me my desired result.
I have this data table:
Current Table
I want this :
Desired header text
My code:
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# Sample data
data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Eve'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 28],
    'Location': ['New York', 'London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Sortable DataTable Example"),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable',
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        sort_action='native', 
        style_table={'overflowX': 'auto'},  
        style_header={
            'text-align': 'left',  
            'minWidth': '200px',
            'whiteSpace': 'normal' 
        },
        style_cell={
            'padding': '10px',  
            'text-align': 'left'  
        }
    )
],) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)



Not sure why you are talking about margins here; your images suggest, that you want the table headers left aligned, instead of centered - so change style_header={ 'text-align': 'center' ...?

@CBroe Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the code and the images to accurately represent my current case and desired outcome. Merci
